# Error: No controller in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Folks,
  I am an AngularJS newbie and I am trying to create a basic HTML hierarchy bound to a model hierarchy using Angular. My top-level module looks like this:

angular.module('fooApp', ['ngResource', 'myList']) which is declared as ng-app="fooApp" at the root div for my page.

I then have HTML that looks like this in my page:

```
<my-item-list/>
```

I have a second module that looks like this:

```
var myList = angular.module('myList', []);
myList.directive('myItemList', function factory() {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        priority: 0,
        templateUrl: '/assets/partials/my-item-list.html',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            // No Op
            $scope.foo = 'bar';
        },
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    // No Op
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    // No OP
                }
            }
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            // No Op
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

The partial HTML template just contains a table and an ng-repeat on a  tag. The template renders just fine, but my JavaScript console contains :

```
Error: No controller: myItemList
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at h (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:41:458)
    at i (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:43:415)
    at http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:48:191
    at http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:94:307
    at h (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:78:33)
    at http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:78:266
    at Object.e.$eval (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:88:347)
    at Object.e.$digest (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:86:198)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/angular.min.js:88:506) <my-item-list>
```

I intend for the nesting to increase (e.g. replace the  in the HTML partial template with another directive and I really need to figure out what I'm doing wrong. It feels like I'm doing some kind of newbie mistake. Whenever I add a 'require' attribute to my directive definition, I get the same "no controller" error message, but with the name of whatever I required (even if I try and require ngRepeat or the page's master controller).

Comment: Set up a plnkr that reproduces your issue... works fine in jsFiddle (which minor changes made): http://jsfiddle.net/EZy2F/.  Do you have `ng-controller` specified anywhere?

Comment: Remember this is more than just a top-level directive. My ng-app is on a div, and I have ng-controller specified on the same top-level div. The main app module has a controller that models the model. The second module (myList) contains the single directive, which has a template URL not a template.

Comment: So, when I take the HTML from my template URL file and place it directly in the template: parameter, all works fine. I only get the "no controller" error message when I use a template URL

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1903 Does your directive really need a controller?  When you remove `controller`, the error appears to go away as well.

Comment: That was it!! I removed the controller: property from the directive definition and it now works with the template URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Angular: http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1903

Does your directive really need a controller?  I would say 9 times out of 10 directives do not need their own controller (mostly they just need `link`).

When you remove `controller` from the directive, the error appears to go away.

Edit: More specifically, it appears that the problem arises when you combine `controller` and `compile`.  Any other combination (controller+link, compile+link, or any by themselves) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this...

Directives should be nested, example,

```
<directive-parent>
  <directive-child></directive-child>
</directive-parent>
```

Check it our here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/SRKL0wZtSew/6sToIKLkRHQJ